# Separating QMA and QCMA

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

A separation between $QMA$ and $QCMA$ remains a notoriously difficult open problem. Even an oracle separation remains elusive. Have there been any recent efforts towards establishing such a separation, either oracular or non-oracular? The most recent I know is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.06750) paper which separates the two classes with respect to an "in-place oracle".